# How do you fill out a motion to modify without the other party's income amounts?

Tags: family-law

It is really that simple.  My state requires certain paperwork for a motion to modify custody (which will modify support), including income and expense statements for both parties.  When you don't know the other party's information, what is the best way to fill this out?

Comment: Subpoena the info from the other party

Comment: @DaleM is on point. Motions to modify, almost by definition, arise in existing and ongoing legal cases where one party has the power to obtain disclosures by some legally mandated means from the other party. Sometimes there is an annual disclosure obligation in the support order, sometimes it is by court rule, sometimes a subpoena in available either from the other party or their employer. Also, while accuracy in income is important, expenses are rarely legally relevant to child support (except extraordinary child related expenses) so accuracy in those is less important.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide your information as much as possible. Once you submit a motion for modification, the other parent or the attorney will provide the information to the court.